# How prevent second or further more update functions when using connectedWith property in jqueryui sortable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.sortable').sortable(
    {
         connectWith:'.sortable',
         update: function()
         {
              alert('sorted');
         }
    });
});
<ul class='sortable'>
   <li>A</li>
   <li>B</li>
   <li>C</li>
</ul>
<ul class='sortable'>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Ok, this alert two times when I sort with ULs. I need one time alert even sorted with UL or Li.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do it.

```
$updated = false;
$('.sortable').sortable(
{
    connectWith: '.sortable',
    stop: function()
    {
        if($updated)
        {
                alert('Updated!');
        }
        $updated = false;
    },
    update: function(e, ui)
    {
        $updated = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like everything OK: when you sort LI's inside single UL then you receive one alert. But if you move LI from one UL to another then you receive two alerts, because each sortable is updated. First loses one LI and second receives it: http://jsfiddle.net/CoolEsh/Kuwzq/1/

If you need alert only when one of the lists updated then do next:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.sortable1').sortable(
    {
         connectWith:'.sortable2'
    });

    $('.sortable2').sortable(
    {
         connectWith:'.sortable1',
         update: function()
         {
              alert('sorted');
         }
    });
});
<ul class='sortable1'>
   <li>A</li>
   <li>B</li>
   <li>C</li>
</ul>
<ul class='sortable2'>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is OK, but if I use lot of lists, I have to write repeat codes for each.

Comment: If you leave your code "as is" than you will always receive 2 alerts when dragging element between sortables: sortable where element coming from changed and sortable where element coming to changed. Maybe its better to handle both changes?